# Xamarin.Android - problem with "android:exported" flag

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm facing the error on publishing my ".aab" on Google Play. It says I need to add "android:exported" flag.
After a week of research, I've tried all the possible solutions that I've found but a solution that can save me I can't use it. The solution sounds like: "Add android:exported flag in your manifest file". The point is I can't add it anywhere because I don't have there any service or intent-filter. I have no idea where I can add this flag.
Below I will show you how my manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="18" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.aa.bb" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="My App"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!--this is necessary for Android v6+ to get the device name and address-->
</manifest>
```

I've tried to add the "android:exported" flag on MainActivity.cs at Activity label but it cause an error. After some research I've understood that if I add there, it will be a duplicate somehow.

**AndroidManifest.xml** from **obj** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This code was generated by a tool.
    It was generated from E:\dev\2021\SmartTestBox\SmartTestBox\SmartTestBox.Android\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    the contents are regenerated.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.aa.bb" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <!-- this is necessary for Android v6+ to get the device name and address -->
  <application android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:icon="@mipmap/iconapp" android:label="My App">
    <receiver android:name="crc64cea48322b3427ae9.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Connectivity Plugin Broadcast Receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="crc64f524f545a0ac0932.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:icon="@mipmap/iconapp" android:label="My App" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="crc64a40206311a3a24ec.BroadcastMonitor" android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:authorities="com.aa.bb.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code of file `AndroidManifest.xml` in folder `obj` of your app?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT thanks for your response! I've searched in obj folder and I've seen that I have 107 files called AndroidManifest.xml. How can I find which one is the good one/used one?

Answer (score 3):

On your class `BroadcastMonitor` you probably have the `[BroadcastReceiver]` attribute on it. This would look something like:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class BroadcastMonitor : BroadcastReceiver
{
}
```

Change it so you explicitly define the `exported` attribute. Like so:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = false)]
public class BroadcastMonitor : BroadcastReceiver
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This can be an another solution instead adding the code into AndroidManifest.xml.